# Client server implementation

Tags: c

After some research I found this code for server side.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
  int listenfd = 0,connfd = 0;

  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

  char sendBuff[1025];  
  int numrv;  

  listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  printf("socket retrieve success\n");

  memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
  memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;    
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);    

  bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

  if(listen(listenfd, 10) == -1){
      printf("Failed to listen\n");
      return -1;
  }


  while(1)
    {

      connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL ,NULL); // accept awaiting request

      strcpy(sendBuff, "Message from server");
      write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));

      close(connfd);    
      sleep(1);
    }


  return 0;
}
```

The thing is from server, I want to send some file to the client, probably in chunks of say 256 bytes.

What is confusing me is that in the code above, you can see `accept` call is made inside loop.
Is it the only way to do it? If it should be in the loop, where do I put the logic of consecutively reading my file, and sending in chunks?
Seems I will need to embed another loop inside `while` loop - just after the `accept` call?

Answer (score 0):

> Seems I will need to embed another loop inside while loop - just
>   after the accept call?

Yes -- you'll need to keep calling write() until all the bytes have been sent.  Keep in mind that write() may write fewer bytes than you asked it to, so you'll need to keep track of write()'s return value to know what arguments to pass to the next write() call.

The example code is ignoring the return value of the write() call, which you can sort of get away with when you're only writing a small number of bytes, but isn't something you'd want to do in real code.

Comment: When attempting to write in chunks of 256 - I guess I should check: if <256 was returned from write, it seems either we reached end of file (assuming I read file before write in chunks of 256) or there was some error right..? (In that case, I will NOT make anymore calls to write...)

Comment: You'll know you reached the end of the file when fread() returns less than the number of bytes you asked it to read in.  As for write(), you shouldn't make assumptions about *why* it processed fewer bytes than you asked it to; just know that it may, and be prepared to handle that possibility.  Also keep in mind that write() could return -1 if an error has occurred (e.g. the remote peer closed the TCP connection on you)

Comment: Indeed, that is what I meant about fread and eof.

Well, if write fails afterwards - I will just assume process failed, other wise there is too much stuff to check (isn't it?).

Comment: and why is `accept` inside the loop? (ps it seems I got it right that I would need another loop for reading/writing :)).

Comment: Sure, as long as you keep in mind that write returns -1 when it fails, and that write() returning a positive number that is less than what the number you passed in is not considered a failure.  As for why the accept() is in the loop, that's so that once a file transfer has completed, the server can then accept() the next connection and serve the next client.

Comment: Thanks. Btw. I am trying to get my head around these client server stuff. About `accept` when is the transfer completed as you refer to it? Once I reach the "close(connfd); sleep(1);" lines?
Also, from the client side, when I `read` in loop- How is data processed, is it read per connection basis? e.g., you establish connection once, and can read in loop?

Comment: Btw. Jeremy, you are welcome to comment here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43914/client-server-implementation-in-c-sending-data-files

Comment: "when is the transfer completed as you refer to it? Once I reach the "close(connfd); sleep(1);" lines?" <-- yes

"when I read in loop- How is data processed, is it read per connection basis?" <-- yes

"e.g., you establish connection once, and can read in loop?" <-- yes