# How to allow simultaneous reading/writing of a file?

Tags: c

I am new in programming C language, but I have to do a project with three micro-controllers, each using a bluetooth device. The micro-controllers have to access a text file on my computer where they update their activity in order to have one of them measuring temperature (Activity1), another controlling a motor (Activity2) and the other waiting (Activity3) or doing something else (Activity4), but not two of them doing the same activity.

I need to program "something" to make this file available to all micro-controllers. For instance, the text file shows:

```
Line 1- Activity1 //for micro1
Line 2- Activity3 //for micro2
Line 3- Activity2 //for micro3
```

After some event, micro1 had to change its activity and update the file

```
Line 1- Activity4 //for micro1
Line 2- Activity3 //for micro2
Line 3- Activity2 //for micro3
```

Here, micro1 only have the Activity4 as a free choice to change, but it knew that through reading the file.

I need you tell me what is that "something"? Do I need a server?

Comment: Yup, you can write a simple server in C. Search these forums for `[c] server` to get some ideas and sample code, e.g. like [this guy's server code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293902/client-server-implementation).

Comment: As it stands, you have four activities and three controllers, so if a controller wants to change activity, there is only one option for what it will do next. That is probably not a long-term feature, though. Are you sure that only one controller can be waiting at a time? You'll need to synchronize access to the file so that only one process is modifying it at a time, and you'll the modifying code probably needs to write to disk immediately. A server process makes sense. The controllers request the server to tell them what to do next (and implicitly state "I'm done on current job").

Comment: Yes, the idea must be extended to more activities, but the control must be synchronized in this file. So the best solution is to implement a server. Any beginners guide that was useful to you? Thanks,

Comment: I found this page http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ and it seems to be a good tutorial.